# Unable to call SAP BAPI function from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, saprfc, bapi

I'm trying to call SAP functions from an Excel macro, VBA. I can do the connection, but whenever the code reaches the line that calls a function, I get the error message

> Run-time error '61704': Internal application error.

My code is the following:

```
Dim functionCtrl As Object
Dim sapConnection As Object
Dim theFunc As Object
Dim PoNumber

Set functionCtrl = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
Set sapConnection = functionCtrl.Connection
sapConnection.System = ""
sapConnection.Client = ""
sapConnection.user = ""
sapConnection.Password = ""
sapConnection.Language = ""

If sapConnection.logon(0, False) <> True Then
MsgBox "No connection to R/3 System"
Exit Sub                                           'End program
End If
Set theFunc = functionCtrl.Add("BAPI_REQUISITION_CREATE")
```

The error comes just when the last line is executed. I've added librfc32.dll in the references, I'm able to execute GUI scripts (recorded from SAP).

Does it have something to do with permissions or something?

Thanks

Comment: Never worked with it but a short Google Search for the Error code points to problems in Authorisations. You might wan to see this? http://scn.sap.com/thread/29386

Comment: I'm new to SAP. I have nothing to do with the SAP system administration or anything, but I have a user account and I have access to requisition creation when working on SAP normally. Shouldn't this be enough for what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

I would not answer exactly your question but I hope to provide useful info anyway.
I currently work on migration of accounting data from QuickBooks to SAP.
I used Ruby and Ruby on Rails for scripting and web interface.

Since you are comfortable with scripting let me recommend to try the following:

- ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [i386-mingw32] with DevKit from http://rubyinstaller.org
- SAP NW RFC SDK (distributed as NWRFC_7-20004566.sar file) - extract sapnwrfc.dll into c:\windows\system32
- SAP NW RFC Ruby library by Pierce Harding from http://www.piersharding.com/download/ruby/sapnwrfc/sapnwrfc-0.24-x86-mingw32-ruby187.gem

Installing Ruby and libraries is really simple.

You may need to create config file:

```
# c:\tmp\sapdev.yml
# adjust parameters to yours
ashost: your.sap.server.ip
sysnr: "00"
client: "100"
user: yoursaplogin
passwd: yoursappwd
lang: EN
trace: "1"
```

Then try something like this:

```
# c:\tmp\sap-test.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'sapnwrfc'

SAPNW::Base.config_location = "c:\\tmp\\sapdev.yml"
SAPNW::Base.load_config
conn = SAPNW::Base.rfc_connect
attrib = conn.connection_attributes
# here you will find if you can connect to SAP programmatically
puts "\n>>> Connection Attributes: #{attrib.inspect}\n"

# discover the BAPI function
call = conn.discover("BAPI_ACC_DOCUMENT_CHECK").new_function_call

# set up parameters. in this case DOCUMENTHEADER, ACCOUNTGL and CURRENCYAMOUNT
call.DOCUMENTHEADER = { 
  "HEADER_TXT" => "EXCEL POST", 
  "COMP_CODE" => "2080", 
  "DOC_DATE" => "20090123", 
  "PSTNG_DATE" => "20090123", 
  "USERNAME" => "YOURSAPLOGIN", 
  "BUS_ACT" => "RFBU", 
  "DOC_TYPE" => "SA" # CUSTOMER INVOICE 
}
puts "\n>>> DOCUMENTHEADER:"
p call.DOCUMENTHEADER

call.ACCOUNTGL = [
  {"ITEMNO_ACC" => "0000000001", "GL_ACCOUNT" =>"0000500000" },
  {"ITEMNO_ACC" => "0000000002", "GL_ACCOUNT" =>"0000799900", "ORDERID" => "CS_USD4110" }
]
puts "\n>>> ACCOUNTGL:"
p call.ACCOUNTGL

call.CURRENCYAMOUNT = [
   {"ITEMNO_ACC" => "0000000001", "CURR_TYPE" => "00", "CURRENCY" => "USD", "AMT_DOCCUR" => "-0.70" }, 
   {"ITEMNO_ACC" => "0000000002", "CURR_TYPE" => "00", "CURRENCY" => "USD", "AMT_DOCCUR" => "0.70" }
]
puts "\n>>> CURRENCYAMOUNT:"
p call.CURRENCYAMOUNT

call.invoke
puts "\n>>> call.RETURN:" 
message = []
call.RETURN.each do |r|
    message << r["MESSAGE"].strip
end
message.uniq!
puts message.join("\n")
```

You may receive errors regarding GL accounts etc. but this is just my working example.
What's important here is to get RFC connection established.
Then you can move on to prepare `BAPI_REQUISITION_CREATE` call, fill in `call.REQUISITION_ITEMS`, invoke it and check `call.RETURN`.

You may also find convenient that Ruby and Ruby on Rails can read data from Excel and integrate with different databases.
This is working for me.

Cheers,

Alexei

Answer (score 0):

To access SAP you will need at a minimun s_RFC. You need to get with your SAP admin section for this and to determine which other authority objects that you might (or might not) need.